# Is the "How to ... ?" question phrase acceptable?

Tags: writing, formality

Is the following sentence acceptable in semi-formal or formal written speech?

> How to adopt a lifestyle that consumes less?

Or ought it be rephrased? For example, to the following?

> How do I adopt a lifestyle that consumes less?

[Context](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4885/recycling/33077#33077).

Comment: Is it "written speech"? Or something with "in writing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context of this sentence is a headline or title, which follow different rules to normal English, and it works perfectly well for that.

You shouldn't use that sentence in regular English, formally or informally; the rephrasing you suggest would be a perfectly acceptable alternative.

Here's an [interesting dissertation on the grammar of headlines](http://dspace.upce.cz/bitstream/10195/34683/1/PraskovaE_GrammarIn_PH_2009.pdf) showing some of the differences.

Comment: Interestingly, question titles on Stack Exchange sites seem to occupy a middle ground between questions and headlines; "[how to](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22how+to%22+site%3Astackexchange.com) do x?" is common, but not as common as a question format like @Peter's rephrased version.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that

> How to adopt a lifestyle that consumes less.

could be used as a title or heading in a written article or question post.  This phrase is only a fragment, because it does not have an independent clause containing a subject-verb relationship.  Because it is a fragment, it should be punctuated as a statement (if at all).  If someone is actually *asking* the question, then use

> How do I adopt a lifestyle that consumes less?

or similar, which is phrased as a question and contains a subject and appropriately conjugated verb.

Comment: or "Tell me how to..."; "The question is: how to..."

Comment: @Unreason, yes, those are good suggestions.

Comment: thanks, can you explain (for my benefit) exactly *why* is the first form a fragment (you can expand it in the answer)? No subject?

Comment: @Unreason You're right, I should have included that explanation.  I'm not sure if what I wrote is clear, though.  What do you think?

Comment: @Unreason: the "How to" phrase does not contain a finite verb ("to adopt" is infinitive) therefore it is not a traditional sentence but a fragment.